# c# .net foreach interface in collection

Tags: c#, .net

What happens if you have a collection of objects that implement various interfaces and you do a `foreach` on that collection for a specific interface (which only some members of the collection implement)? Is it possible to skip the members that don't implement that interface?

```
interface IFoo {}
interface IBar {}

class Foo : IFoo {}
class Baz : IFoo, IBar {}
```

...

```
var foos = new List<IFoo> ();

foos.Add(new Foo());
foos.Add(new Baz());

foreach (IBar bar in foos)
{
    // What happens now?
}
```

Comment: Did you try it? What's the result?

Comment: Use LINQ to skip other types: `foreach(IBar bar in foo.OfType<IBar>() { ... }`

Comment: @Erno make an answer out of this.

Comment: @gdoron - I didn't add it as an answer because it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Erno I rephrased the question, Jeopardy style.

Comment: @jackvsworld - I see no reason to add an answer because gdoron already covered this. If that answer didn't cover your question, make sure you change the question. Also do not use strike-through in the question. If needed we can see the history of the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
foreach (IBar bar in foo)
{
    // What happens now?
}
```

> // What happens now?

Nothing happens now, as you already got an `InvalidCastException` in the first row...

**WHY?**

`foreach` statements are being translated to something like:

```
foreach (object f in foo)
{
    IBar bar = (IBar) f;

    ...
}
```

There is an implicit cast in the `foreach statement`
Which allows you to write stupid things like the following without Compilation time error:

```
var foo  = new List<string>{ "111", "222","333"};
foreach (IBar bar in foo) // InvalidCastException at runtime.
{
    ...
}
```

You can use LINQ as suggested by @Erno to get only the objects that implement the `IBar` interface:

```
foreach(IBar bar in foo.OfType<IBar>())
```

Which is like:

```
foo.Where(f => f is IBar)
```